# Error when trying to add tailwind full color pallete

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am facing an issue with adding the complete color palette. I want to access all the colors mentioned in the documentation.

I made changes in the *tailwind.config.js* file. When using, nothing happens on the render.
Please let me know what can I do to fix it.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Build your palette here
      transparent: "transparent",
      current: "currentColor",
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      red: colors.red,
      blue: colors.sky,
      yellow: colors.amber,
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Usage:

```
import React from "react";
export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h1 className="text-colors-blue">This is the Contact page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```